# Clear input field on button click in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I know this is a common question , but I am facing problem in this. I am unable to refresh by input fields on button click.

When I am clicking button , the information is sent and added up in a list. So whenever I click it the input fields must get cleared/refresh (not page load).

***View:***

```
<div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="reg_input">Name</span>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" ng-model="ff.Name" required>
</div>

<div class="input-group">   
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="reg_input">Block</span>
     <input class="form-control" id="bl" type="text" ng-model="ff.Block" required>
</div>

<div class="input-group">   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ip" type="text" ng-model="ff.IP" ng-maxlength="2" style="width: 30px" required>
</div>
   <a class="btn btn-md btn-primary" ng-click="getClick(ff)">Add</a>
```

Is there any refresh predefined in bootstrap button ?

**EDIT controller:-**

```
$scope.list = {};
                $scope.array_of_Names = [];
              $scope.getClick= function() {
                 $scope.master = angular.copy($scope.ff);
                  $http.post("url", $scope.list).success(function(data) { 
                        $scope.AllData= data;
                        $scope.addInfo.Segments.push($scope.list);
                        $scope.ff.Name = "";
                        $scope.ff.Block= "";
                        $scope.ff.IP= "";
                        $scope.array_of_Names.push($scope.list);
                       console.log("Segment successfully created");

                  },function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                       // growl.error("Something went wrong");
                  });
                     console.log($scope.master);
                };
```

Comment: what is `getClick` ? where is the main logic ?

Comment: Just initialize your forms ng-model value to its default values on click event.

Comment: @AshishRatan added. Please check

Comment: @ManishBalodia ok I will try.

Comment: $scope.ff= {} will work . inside ur http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Try it!. All property under $scope.ff will be reset.

```
$scope.ff={};
```

And you can apply it in your code part like this:

```
$scope.list = {};
            $scope.array_of_Names = [];
          $scope.getClick= function() {
             $scope.master = angular.copy($scope.ff);
              $http.post("url", $scope.list).success(function(data) { 
                    $scope.ff={};
                    $scope.AllData= data;
                    $scope.addInfo.Segments.push($scope.list);
                    $scope.array_of_Names.push($scope.list);
                   console.log("Segment successfully created");

              },function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                   // growl.error("Something went wrong");
              });
                 console.log($scope.master);
            };
```

Comment: Ok where I need to put that?

Comment: Nope, no changes brother.

Comment: @WhoAmI i don't know the full business, but please try to place $scope.ff={}; after success. edited my answer.

Comment: could you upload your code to plnkr, i'll try your code later.

Comment: Thanks , it is working. `$scope.ff={};` should be after push , as it was sending null earlier.

Comment: Welcome @WhoAmI, happy coding life.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

```
$scope.getClick= function() {
    $scope.master = angular.copy($scope.ff);
    $scope.ff = {};
    $http.post("url", $scope.list).success(function(data) { 
           $scope.AllData= data;
           $scope.addInfo.Segments.push($scope.list);
           $scope.array_of_Names.push($scope.list);
           console.log("Segment successfully created");
        },function (data, status, headers, config) { 
          // growl.error("Something went wrong");
        }).error(function(err) {
            console.log("Error: ", err);
        });
        console.log($scope.master);
 };
```

Comment: I did that , I have updated the edit but didn't get refreshed.

Comment: Are you sure your request enter in successs or error function please make sure in what case enter your request with console.log

Comment: Please try this after your console.log($scope.master); write this $scope.ff = {};

Comment: You mean to say `$scope.list` ? yes its successful . But the return data is not these which I am passing . I need to clear input fields before POST happens.

Comment: Is there any error you get or somethink like that? If no then please console.log($scope.ff) after $scope.ff = {};

Comment: No error , console is showing my input `{Name: "df", Block: "C", IP: "10.20.30.40"}` . My fields are not getting refreshed yet.

Comment: Check my code and make sure is the same as your because what i show is work perfectly for me

Comment: Please edit your question and show your getClick function how is look right now

Comment: Thanks for your help . Its working fine now . Just I get this `$scope.ff = {};` after POST function as it was sending  null earlier. So now its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `then` instead of `success`

```
$scope.getClick = function(ff){
  $scope.master = angular.copy($scope.ff);
              $http.post("url", $scope.list).then(function(data) { 
                    $scope.AllData= data;
                    $scope.addInfo.Segments.push($scope.list);
                    $scope.ff.Name = "";
                    $scope.ff.Block= "";
                    $scope.ff.IP= "";
                    $scope.array_of_Names.push($scope.list);
                   console.log("Segment successfully created");

              },function (data, status, headers, config) { 
                   // growl.error("Something went wrong");
              });
                 console.log($scope.master);
}
```

Comment: Tried this but nothing happened. Please check my controller . Accordingly I need to do

Comment: Doesn't matter , it's same . Ok I explain  Name Block and IP is user input not response. I need to clear this value before POST happens